# Error inflating fragment xml

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, textview, fatal-error

I'm trying to update a textview in a fragment based on a passed intent, but I keep getting an error. Here is my code:

```
public class PlayerDisplayFragment extends Fragment {

public PlayerDisplayFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_display, container, false);

    String[] playerArray = getArguments().getStringArray("playerArray");
    updateText(view,playerArray);

    return view;
}

public void updateText (View view , String[] playerArray){

    String pName = playerArray[0] + " " + playerArray[1];
    TextView playerName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.player_name);
    playerName.setText(pName);

}
}
```

The code crashes when it tries to execute the updateText function. Here is the xml element (in the fragment xml file) that it refers to:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Placeholder"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:id="@+id/player_name"
    android:gravity="center">
</TextView>
```

And lastly, here is the error:

```
26609-26609/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.soccerstar, PID: 26609
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.soccerstar/com.example.android.soccerstar.PlayerDisplay}:
                           android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:393)
   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2172)
   at com.example.android.soccerstar.PlayerDisplay.onCreate(PlayerDisplay.java:13)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

edit: full xml here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.soccerstar.PlayerDisplayFragment">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/placeholder_m"
            android:background="#7b7b7b"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/PlayerPhoto"/>
        />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="You matched Lionel Messi!"
            android:layout_below="@+id/PlayerPhoto"
            android:id="@+id/MatchText">
            </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/MatchText"
            >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Your Name"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:text="Born on April 15, 1992"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:text="Is 5 foot 11 inches tall."
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:text="Weighs 160 lbs."
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:text="Prefers right foot"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:text="American Nationality"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:gravity="center">
                    </TextView>

                </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Lionel Messi"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:id="@+id/player_name"
                    android:gravity="center">
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Born on April 15, 1992"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Is 5 foot 11 inches tall."
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Weighs 160 lbs."
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Prefers right foot"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                </TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="American Nationality"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center">
                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is from the main activity:

```
public class PlayerDisplay extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_display); <--- THIS IS LINE 13
}
```

Here is the activity_player_display.xml file:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.android.soccerstar.PlayerDisplayFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_player_display"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".PlayerDisplay" />
```

Where I feed in the array from the main fragment:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), com.example.android.soccerstar.PlayerDisplay.class);
            intent.putExtra("playerArray", playerArray);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: can you post full fragment xml code?

Comment: If `@+id/player_name` is in the **fragment** xml, then why are you trying to find it in the activity at `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.player_name)`? That isn't how you get views in a fragment

Comment: jayanth - it's pretty long. anything in particular you're looking for?

cricket - yeah i realize i'm definitely doing something wrong. how would you fix the problem/get a view in a fragment?

Comment: post the code where you set up the arguments values in fragment.

Comment: what do you mean @jaydroider?

Comment: @NBC :your put string array values.

Comment: That's not the issue. When I run a log of the array, it comes through just fine. But I edited it in.

Comment: How are you initializing your fragment?

Comment: I posted the code where I call the fragment (last section)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Bundle in your Main Fragment like this.

```
Fragment fragment = new PlayerFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putStringArray("playerArray", playerArray);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And in your Player Fragment getArguments.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if(bundle != null){
    String[] playerArray = getArguments().getStringArray("playerArray");
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @NBC: have you replaced the fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. It was so simple!

That line 13 code that was being referenced, it was from the main activity of the fragment. It was referencing the main activity xml file instead of the fragment xml file. So I changed it:

public class PlayerDisplay extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_display); <--- THIS IS LINE 13
}
```

to

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_player_display); <--- THIS IS LINE 13
}
```

And now it works! Thanks all.